# How to translate an actionItem in Nativescript

Tags: ios, localization, nativescript, uinavigationbar, translation

So we have our app using this default actionItem everywhere. The text is never specified other than setting the item to `ios.systemIcon="2"` this seems to set the text to "Edit". I could change this to a custom actionItem to change the text, but it seems like there should be an easier way to do this. Does nativescript have a builtIn way to handle translations in the actionItems?

```xml
          <ActionItem
            ios.position="left"
            ios.systemIcon="2"
            (tap)="onEditTap()"
          ></ActionItem>
```

Comment: You may always have both icon and text together by setting `text` attribute. Icon is more like an image, you may set custom icon. Did that answer your question?

Comment: We're not setting text anywhere, and I even think text gets ignored if I set `ios.systemIcon="2"` this corresponds to a default button saying "Edit"

Comment: Here is a playground example: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=7jHvq0

Comment: Sorry, what I said above is applicable for Android not iOS. In Android you can have both system icon and text. With iOS, system icon overrides text. Reg, internalization on the system button - looks like the buttons are displayed only on preferred / default language (one you set using `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key in info.plist). If you like to dynamically change the string based on current language, you may have to use a custom text instead of system icon.

Comment: I already tried changing the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to "fr", but that didn't change any values. I'm not sure if I need to add some sort of translation strings for Apple? or do anything else?

Comment: Try a clean build, if you are only looking for french then setting CFBundleDevelopmentRegion to fr should have solved this. If you still have issues, please share a sample project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208939/discussion-between-felipe-centeno-and-manoj).

Comment: For anybody interested, I just replaced the `ios.systemIcon="2"` with our own text: `[text]="''edit' | translate"`

Comment: I see the issue, `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` didn't work as expected. Anyways translating on your own is good and cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

I tried switching `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to "fr", but that didn't change the action buttons as expected. I ended up getting rid of ios.systemIcon, and passing my own text. My code now looks like this:

```
<ActionItem
  ios.position="left"
  [text]="'edit' | translate"
  (tap)="onEditTap()"
></ActionItem>
```